Can I use a formula to define cell names in Excel?
I have a large Excel table where I need to define names for each cell.
At the moment, I am doing this manually, one by one (which is taking forever):
(Example table)

Is there a way that I could incorporate a formula that speeds this process up for me?
In essence, I want to do this (see below picture) but with defining cell names rather than adding text to the boxes.

I'd appreciate any assistance, thank you!

You could do it with VBA. Though naming every cell in a table does seem suboptimal. What's the end goal?

Why "Vegetable_Cabbage" but not "Year_2022"?  Do you have other classes for the vertical column?  Seems like INDEX() with a couple of MATCH()'s might be a simpler approach to locating the required cell.

This macro performs the complete job:
Sub NameIt()
  Dim i As Long, n, a
  n = Application.Evaluate("TOROW(F8&""_""&F9:F13&""_""&G7:I7)")
  a = Application.Evaluate("TOROW(""=""&{""$G"",""$H"",""$I""}&""$""&SEQUENCE(5,,9))")
  For i = 1 To UBound(n)
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=n(i), RefersTo:=a(i)
  Next
End Sub


Without VBA, it is relatively easy to automatically create the names of the corresponding columns and rows. The Create from Selection tool Ctrl+Shift+F3 is used for this.
Column names must be preceded by an underscore (they cannot be numbers), row names can be easily prepared with simple formulas. Then select the entire area with the names and invoke Ctrl+Shift+F3. In the dialog box, select the Top Row and Left Column.
When the names are created, we can use them in two ways, either directly, e.g.
=Vegetable_Cabbage _2023
The order of names is arbitrary, there must be a space between the names.
Or indirectly, using the INDIRECT function. There must also be a space between the references:
=INDIRECT(B3) INDIRECT(D1)


I think it's not that difficult in VBA. Something like this:
For Each c In Range("G9", "I13").Cells
   ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=c.Value, RefersTo:="=" & c.Address
Next


First enter to G9 the formula =F8&"_"&F9:F13&"_"&G7:I7.

We should remove or replace spaces.
Code
Sub DefineTableBodyNames(TableRange As Range)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim Name As String
    For r = 2 To TableRange.Rows.Count
        For c = 2 To TableRange.Columns.Count
            Name = TableRange.Cells(r, 1).Value & "_" & TableRange.Cells(1, c).Value
            Name = Replace(Name, "  ", "_")
            TableRange.Cells(r, c).Name = Name
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Usage

DefineTableBodyNames Range("F7:I13")



I agree with BigBen, it seems not the best solution depending where you are going to use is for.
In VBA you can also use something like this:
    Sub Macro1()
    For Each Item In Selection
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Names.Add Name:=Cells(2, 1).Value & "_" & Cells(Item.Row, 1).Value & "_" & Cells(1, Item.Column).Value, RefersTo:="=Sheet1!" & Item.Address
    Next
End Sub

